# [Not A Type release]: message sent to deallocated instance in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I get a crash when quickly scrolling through a `UITableView`. 
The crash is :

```
  *** -[Not A Type release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1aded1c0
```

And the exception breakpoint indicates this as the source:

```
- (void)updateInfo:(Item*)item{
    if (!item) {
        return;
    }
    Program *prg = (Program *)item;
    self.titleLabel.text = prg.title; // crash here
    self.descriptionLabel.text = prg.item_description;

}
```

This method is inside the custom table view cell subclass and it is called when data from the internet is ready to be displayed in the cell.
I have never seen this kind of crash before...

What is the best way to fix it?

Comment: Please paste your .h file for your custom cell and cellFroRow method here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reason:**
As you scroll the tableview, the cells on top get released and when data comes from internet for those cell, they have already been released. So, change your logic. You generally receive this error when you try to access and update an object which has already been released. As you are saying that this method is inside your custom cell, so it clearly indicates that the cell is already released. That's why your app gets crashed when you try to update any view of that cell.

**Solution:**
Either you can reload your whole tableview or reload those specific cells when you receive data.

Answer (score 2):

Where are you calling the method "updateInfo"? You should call this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You should not store a reference to a cell and then call this.

When you get the data from your service you just call `self.tableView reloadData` (or perhaps `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` if you know which row needs update and dont want a performance hit)

Comment: & Salman The logic is that the cell will call an adapter to get the date from the internet and get a callback when the date is available. So I think that is the problem ... I need to deregister the cell from the adapter......

Comment: Yes, it seems dangerous. If you have a property (i.e. delegate) you can declare it as weak and it should fix the problem. But if you have multiple cells in the adapter then I'm not so sure.

Comment: Do you have multiple callbacks for each cell or is it just one big blob of data? You should rethink your pattern if it's just a big blob of data and all cells will get populated at the same time.